# Set Binding in ItemsSource in DataGrid programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

I have the next XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="some_name" AutoGenerateColumns="False">   
                <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                    <Binding XPath="Setting/Element[@Name='...']/Field"/>
                </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Type}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Count" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Count}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="80" Binding="{Binding XPath=@ID}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>                    
            </DataGrid>
```

How can I set `Binding` with `XPath="Setting/Element[@Name='...']/Field"` in the C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the binding like this.

```
    var binding = new Binding
    {
        Source = _viewModel,
        XPath = "Setting/Element[@Name='...']/Field"
    };

    some_name.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```